# I'm confused about the bad feedback my question got

Tags: support

[image]

I recently opened my account in Stack Overflow, and there is written in the tour "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers", "This site is all about getting answers". Now, I asked on the site "I want to sell a python executable (made with PyInstaller), which would be sold in a zip folder. How can I prevent that somebody sells it or gives it for free by copying it?

I hope to make sure my code can't be used by somebody that didn't buy it, like big companies surely do. How can I achieve that?". I got in a matter of hours seven downvotes! It also got closed, because "Closed. This question is not about programming or software development. It is not currently accepting answers.". Why not? I thought it was about programming. If not, could somebody please tell me what forum I should use? I even got muted for one day.

I deleted it, as I was losing reputation.

Comment: The question is extremely broad.

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394422/protecting-software-from-copying-piracy (and the linked questions in the comments) and tags like [tag:copy-protection] or [tag:anti-piracy].

Comment: Would be helpful to include a screenshot of the question.

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: Topicality aside, I'm pretty sure the answer to that question is "you can't". If those "big companies" you mentioned haven't figured out how to prevent software piracy, then frankly, you don't stand a chance.

Comment: But why is even this one getting such bad votes? Did I say anything bad?

Comment: It's not a specific question, that'd that real problem. It's not asking for specific programming advice.

Comment: When you hover over the down arrow for the vote, it says something like "This question does not show any research effort". Do you believe your question showed any research effort?

Comment: Side note: Reputation is nice and all, it grants site privileges, but reputation has either no effect or such a small effect the we out here in the community can't see it on the server's computation of how often you can ask questions. The score of the question, on the other hand, directly impacts when the server will allow you to ask questions, and deleting the question doesn't remove the question from the server's computations. Many new users casually delete poorly received questions and are stunned when the server stops accepting their questions.

Comment: That said, this question you could not fix without fundamentally changing the question (a frowned-on behaviour) and is better off deleted. But in general, reserve deleting a question for the last resort or as a temporary measure to avoid more downvotes, closure, or community deletion while you improve the question. Always prefer to improve the question because, as far as we can tell, the server never forgets and never forgives.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to start a discussion about the topic?

Comment: "Why not? I thought it was about programming." - I don't understand how you came to that conclusion. If I own a grocery store and I ask a question about how to keep the fresh produce from spoiling in the display case, is that a question about agriculture? If I own a broken appliance and ask a question about how to fix it, is that a question about manufacturing?

Comment: Stack Overflow still wouldn't be the right place for the discussion because you aren't discussing software. At least not at this stage. I  recommend a more-than-cursory examination of the publicly available literature of the topic before starting a discussion so that you can get to the portions of the topic that pertain to programming and rein in the scope. Discussions are more free-form than the Q&A, but you still need to be able to guide the discussion.

Comment: *"This site is all about getting answers"* - to programming problems. And you're supposed to try your best to search for existing answers. You just can't learn how this site works by reading the sales pitch I'm afraid. This site is like an ogre, it has layers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How can I prevent that somebody sells it or gives it for free by copying it?

You can't. And that question is at best a human behavior question, maybe a legal question but it certainly isn't a programming question.

The problem you try to solve is way too broad, has many challenges and is riddled with unsolved traps, technically and legally. And more often than not all that effort has limited success.

That you think this is just a programming problem is a sign for lack of research. You can maybe ask for how to implement a license key protection or maybe for a deployment method ties the software to a device but that is far away from your actual question.

You might be better off with a [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions) and then come back with a concrete question that has single answer of a few paragraphs.

If you sell your zip file for $1,000,000 then maybe buyers are reluctant to give it for free by copying it because they paid a high price for it.

Comment: "That you think this is just a programming problem is a sign for lack of research." Just use AI!